# Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports

Tags: 22.04, tor

I am using UBUNTU 22 (Jammy)

1. I have installed anonsurf
2. Also have TOR
3. TOR Browser is installed as well

Here are many `torrc` files in my system:

```
/etc/anonsurf/torrc
/etc/tor/torrc
/home/linux/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc
/home/linux/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc-defaults
/home/linux/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc.orig.1
/home/linux/Downloads/anonsurf-ubuntu/torrc
/usr/share/doc/tor/torrc.sample.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/torrc.5.gz
/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc
/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc-instances
```

Here I noticed that `/etc/default/tor` is not listed when located `torrc`

I amm facing the following warnings/errors when start my tor:
[image: tor command output]

I also uninstalled and installed tor but not fixed
Please help me to fix this problem

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

[tor](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/tor.1.html) isn't a browser. To install Tor browser use the [torbrowser-launcher](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/torbrowser-launcher.1.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher
torbrowser-launcher
```

Comment: I am not talking about tor BROWSER. I am looking for the solution of TOR

Comment: @Raakh You are using `tor-browser` tag. the `torbrowser-launcher` will configure `tor` apparmor profil for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I edited and removed `torbrowser` tag